# I downloaded my chrome bookmarks to move to a new computer and it saved as a XML instead of HTML - when I try to convert i get an error

Tags: html, xml, file-conversion

I tried using several conversions -- I've used Altova and a couple of other free software options.  I don't know how to add the XML file for you to view but would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

When I use the **Export Bookmarks** option on Chrome browser, by default, the only option it allows is to save as an HTML file. If you did mistakenly save as an XML file, then using an XML editor like use probably used from Altova will most likely create more errors.

1) I'd suggest, you first right-click on the XML bookmarks file and go to `Properties` tab and see if you can restore the oldest, least-modified version of it.

2) Then simply try renaming the extension of the bookmarks file from `.xml` to `.html` to see if it now works.